# How to avoid elements transitioning from top of page with transition

Tags: css, vue.js

My elements seems to transition or "fly" in from the top of my page. This is not what I want as I want them to transition from the row  to which they belong. How can I achieve this behaviour?

Vue template looks like this.

```
 <li class="accordion-parent" v-for="(parent, pIndex) in list" :key="pIndex">
  <div class="accordion-entry">
    <div
      @click="() => toggleExpand(pIndex)"
      :class="[{ expanded: expanded === pIndex }, outerDiv]"
    >
        <table class="accordion-expanded">
      <transition-group name="fade" tag="v-layout" class="manual-v-layout">
        <tbody
          v-for="index in 10"
          :key="index"
          class="cycle"
          v-show="expanded === pIndex"
        >

        <tr class="view-more-row" v-show="expanded === pIndex">
              <td />
              <td class="view-more-cell">
                <span> View more cycles </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody key="id">
          <transition name="fade">
            <tr class="view-more-row" v-show="expanded === pIndex">
              <td />
              <td class="view-more-cell">
                <span> View more cycles </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </transition>
        </tbody>
      </transition-group>
    </table>
   </div>
  </li>
```

Vue script

```
<script>
    export default {
  name: "AnalyticsAccordion",
    data() { return { list: [1,2,3,4] }
},};
 </script>
```

Css

```
 <style>
    tbody {
         transition: 0.5s;
         width: 100%;
              }
    
    .manual-v-layout {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: Please could you put your code into a snippet that we can run to see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Having said that, a possible explanation is that the row doesn't have an explicit position so the system hunts back to find the nearest ancestor which has, hence they 'fly in' from the top.